# What does "category" in the manifest mean?

Tags: android, categories

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addCategory(java.lang.String)) says you can specify a custom category.

- When, why and how would you do it?
- What would be the use of it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The way I understand it, categories are public directives to the android operating system(and other apps) that represent different categories that your app should be a part of.

Example

- When the launcher icon is tapped on the home screen, the home application looks through every installed app's manifest for the `HOME` category -- and if so it displays it in the app drawer.

However, there's more. You can specify categories in your applications manifest that lets the system know that you application can handle the intent category. For example, by putting a `ALTERNATIVE` category, other apps in the system know that your app can handle that category without specifically knowing the action name! In the following example, custom intent categories are passed through this intent, which is filtered and the corresponding object gets edited(taken from the Notes example app):

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/resolve_title">
 <action android:name="com.android.notepad.action.EDIT_TITLE" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE" />
 <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note" />
</intent-filter>
```

By registering this intent filter in an `<activity />` tag, you can edit a "note". The intent data would contain the note, and the intent would get routed to the activity that this filter is registered in.

**In Conclusion:**

There isn't really a reason you'd use a custom category. They are for Android, and thus don't really make sense in application use. But, if you choose to use them, they can be used in the methods described above. "They provide some specific semantic rules, and if those rules are useful to you then feel free to use them"(Hackbod).

Comment: could you make your own category though? something like <category android:name="com.custom.myCategory" />

Comment: If you scroll down to addCategory() you will find - Parameters

category The desired category. This can be either one of the predefined Intent categories, or a custom category in your own namespace.

Comment: There is really no such thing as "your own category" or a "custom category."  Like the action, these are just strings, in a global universe-wide namespace.  There are some standard Intent protocols defined by the platform in the android.* namespace, but there is nothing special about them.  They provide some specific semantic rules, and if those rules are useful to you then feel free to use them...  keeping in mind you need to scope them to be in your own namespace.

Comment: @hackbod hmm makes sense I guess. If you'd make it as an answer I'd award you the bounty :)

Comment: What is meaning of `selected alternative` category?

Answer (score 5):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Scroll down a bit and you should see a section under "Intent Objects"

They basically describe certain special properties of an activity. for example, adding

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

means that the app can be started on the phone's bootup

Comment: i am more interested in custom categories. could not find any mention of that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm kinda a noob to Android still, although I have programming experience otherwise..  It says a custom category `in your own namespace`.  I'm guessing that if you are programming multiple apps and you want one app to run another app, you could use a custom category for your intent to force the phone to find your other app to catch the intent with?

Comment: Basically we can use intent action filter to ensure communication between activities. What is the benefit of use category filter ?

Answer (score 2):

When you do not want to use the default category then use the custom category.
Custom categories should use the package name as a prefix, to ensure that they are unique.
Some information is provided on below link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element.html 
Check the below link it has somewhat same question:
[Android custom categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681053/android-custom-categories)

Comment: yeah, I read that. But in the question its not working for them, and there is no answer.