# What exactly is the purpose of CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE

Tags: android, android-intent, categories, intentfilter

I've been reading through the documentation on [CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE:kotlin.String) and I'm wondering what exactly is meant by "an alternative action to the data the user is currently viewing".

Could someone provide more examples of how this category is used?

I've found only some information about creating [Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#intents) and also some quote "When the system offers the user a choice of activities to do a job, the system lists activities with filters possessing this category". But then again, in the 2nd case - how does this work if we need to include CATEGORY_DEFAULT in order for an activity to receive implicit intents.

Comment: Related: [What does "category" in the manifest mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782820/what-does-category-in-the-manifest-mean), especially the accepted answer

Comment: So does this mean that `"For example, by putting a ALTERNATIVE category, other apps in the system know that your app can handle that category without specifically knowing the action name"` - by putting an 'ALTERNATIVE' category, we can add out app to some chooser (e.g. by opening an image we see apps which can handle images, and our app will be there)? Will it be specific like in the example with images, i.e. will it show for images chooser? Or will it appear just for any chooser?

Comment: It is just I'm confused about how we can specify this 'alternative', alternative to what? And how the system decides about handling many apps with 'alternative' category especially without knowing the action name

Comment: I guess the system will offer the app based on 1) a matching mime-type in the data tag and 2) the 'ALTERNATIVE' category. I will set up a small sample to better understand what is happening and get back to you (may take a few days)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you're using some messenger app and a friend sent you an interesting link. Then there are several things you could do with it:

- open it in a browser
- share it with another person
- maybe save it in some notes app
- ...

If you take the link as "data you are currently viewing" then it would be nice if the messenger offered you an option to select the appropriate action from a bundle of alternative actions which are currently available on your device.

With `Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE` and `Menu.addIntentOptions()`, the framework has a way for the app which is the initital "owner" of some type of data to offer the user access to further actions. These actions can be implemented by any app which is running on the device and which announced its capability of handling this specific data type by an entry in the `Manifest.xml`, more specifically in the `<intent-filter>` tag.

Let's consider a very simple - if not very realistic - example:

My app has some `String` value which it displays to the users. Alternative actions could be

- parsing the `String` based on some regex
- sorting the letters of the `String`
- transforming the `String`, e.g. to upper case letters
- ...

My app will have its `Activity` or `Fragment` override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` as follows (code snippet for a `Fragment`)

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);

    // Create an Intent that describes the requirements to fulfill, to be included
    // in our menu. The offering app must include a category value of Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE.
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Lorem ipsum");
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);

    // Search and populate the menu with acceptable offering applications.
    menu.addIntentOptions(
            R.id.intent_group,  // Menu group to which new items will be added
            0,      // Unique item ID (none)
            0,      // Order for the items (none)
            this.getActivity().getComponentName(),   // The current activity name
            null,   // Specific items to place first (none)
            intent, // Intent created above that describes our requirements
            0,      // Additional flags to control items (none)
            null);  // Array of MenuItems that correlate to specific items (none)
}
```

The `Activity`s which are able to handle the given `String` will declare an `IntentFilter` as child tag of their  tag in the `Manifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".ToUpperCaseActivity">
      <intent-filter android:label="@string/label_action_text_to_uppercase">
            <action android:name="de.ddvsidedown.alternativeoptionsapp.action.ALL_CAPS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

or

```
<activity android:name=".SortActivity">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/label_action_sort_text">
            <action android:name="de.ddvsidedown.alternativeoptionsapp.action.SORT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then my app will show the following popup menu when the user taps the overflow icon...

[image: popup menu with "Text to upper case" and "Sort text"]

... and the runtime will navigate directly to the chosen `Activity`. There, the text can be retrieved as follows:

```
 if(getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {

        char[] ca = getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT).toString().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(ca);
        String message = buildString(ca);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + message);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
        textView.setText(message);
}
```

Please note that the exact code for retrieving the data depends on the data type, just like with "normal" `Intent`s with no `<category>` tag at all or with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` in the `<intent-filter>` .

> how does this work if we need to include CATEGORY_DEFAULT in order for an activity to receive implicit intents

You need `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>` in the `<intent-filter>` of an `Activity` if you want it to appear in a chooser dialog. By the way, an `Activity` can have multiple `<intent-filter>` tags

Let's modify the example: my app also has "SHARE" `Button`. If it is clicked, the following piece of code is executed:

```
 /**
 * Will only work with <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 */
private void shareText() {
    // Create the text message with a string
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    //sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Lorem ipsum");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

    // Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
    if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
}
```

The runtime will show a chooser dialog to the user. Each `Activity` with an `<intent-filter>` with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>` will be shown with the app title and the app's launcher icon. (While it is possible to have two `Activity`s with `CATEGORY_DEFAULT` in the same app, it is clear that this does not look good - it may be possible to tweak the text and/ or icon but that's definitely out of the scope of this question)

If I comment out the `ACTION_SEND` then the chooser dialog has the title "Complete action using" whereas if I set `ACTION_SEND`, the title is "Share with".

> how [does] the system decide[...] about handling many apps with 'alternative' category especially without knowing the action name

My app configures its `Intent` by setting (or omitting) the action, the categories as well as the data type. The runtime always chooses `Activity`s which match all requirements of my `Intent`. This means, the other `Activity` may offer to handle data type "text/*" instead of just "text/plain" but if it only offers "image/*" then it won't be shown to the user.

Comment: This is very informative and helpful. Thank you a lot!